# Is it safe to install Ubuntu's .deb packages on debian? Are .deb packages universal?

Tags: linux, debian, packages, debian-buster, appimage

Case in point, [AppImage Launcher](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/releases/tag/v2.2.0)

I wanted to install the .deb package for it but they only had options for bionic and xenial. I am running debian 10 buster. So I wasn't sure with how unstable linux is, if it would be the right choice to install it.

Answer (score 1):

**It's not safe.**

Apparently even Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic) and Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) need different packages, despite them both being Ubuntu. Even more so Debian, which is not Ubuntu.

DEBs are built with specific operating systems in mind. Debian uses the same DEB format as Ubuntu (actually Ubuntu uses Debian's DEB format), but it's a different system and assumptions that were made for a particular version of Ubuntu may not hold for Debian.

Sometimes an Ubuntu package will work for Debian or vice versa. But there are no guarantees and a simple uninstall may not reverse the changes completely if you're installing on an unsupported system.

Comment: Haste makes waste, well I regret not waiting another min. I just got done installing it right when the notification arrived. And what you said is exactly what happened, sort of. The images were crashing even before I installed the launcher and I thought the launcher might aid me but it didn't help if anything I ended up removing the launcher as well as the 2 files. Now after I removed everything, it still left a lot of residue in my system and created a big mess .Now I am trying to get rid of it. Here's the link to another [post I made](https://bit.ly/3bIwnPj) in case you might know what to do

Comment: Here's a Debian wiki link about this: https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian